# Ignore missing of overloading when decorator is present

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am using experimental decorators with TypeScript in React.

The library I'm using for the forms is from Ant Design and the decorator inserts a `form` property to my component.

I have a `Component` declaration like this:

```
interface IProps {
  form: any
}
@Form.create()
class Component extends React.Component<IProps> { ... }
```

Now when I want to use that Component without the `form` property like so

```
<Component/>
```

I get following TS Error

> TS2769
>
> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): Component', gave the following error.
>       Property 'form' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IProps, context?: any): Component', gave the following error.
>       Property 'form' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

Now I could just make the `form` property optional with the `?` notation, but its not nice, and when I want to further type `form` like so

```
interface IFields {
    "name": string;
}
interface IProps extends FormComponentProps<IFields> { ... }
```

it really becomes unfeasible.

What way do I have to tell TypeScript that the `form` property is injected via a decorator?

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: No I did even file an issue https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/2052